# DBD::SQLite: Insert or Update - Question

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi, sql-update, sql-insert

While writing my question (howto: insert a new entry and if it exists already, update it) I found some answers in the `Related Questions`:

```
$sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO $table ( Id, Name, Rating ) VALUES( ?, ?, ? )";
$sth_rating = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth_rating->execute( $id, $name, $rating );
```

.

```
$sql = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table ( Id, Name, Rating ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )";
$sth_rating = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth_rating->execute( $id, $name, $rating );

$sql = "UPDATE $table SET Rating = ? WHERE Id = ?";
$sth_rating = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth_rating->execute( $rating, $id );
```

Is the second method more safe then the first one?

Comment: Are you wanting to replace an existing field completely or just update its rating if it exists? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert

Comment: All fields except "Rating" come from another table and are always the same (for that id).
Normally, the entries are added but if they already exist, a possible new "Rating" value should be adjusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second method is *less* safe because it is non-atomic.  In other words, it happens in more than one step.  Consider two processes both updating the same data.  Time is moving down.

```
Process 1                      Process 2

INSERT OR IGNORE...
                               INSERT OR IGNORE...
                               UPDATE...
UPDATE...
```

Process 1 starts first, but Process 2 sneaks in and does its update between.  Process 1 then blows right over Process 2's update.

This isn't so bad in this particular situation, both processes are going to blow over each other no matter what, but you can easily get yourself into trouble by extending your technique.

(Unless I misunderstood the question and what you want is an [upsert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert))